# URL duplicate issue in SEO-MOZ report

Tags: string, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Specifications :

1. Language : PHP
2. DB : MYSQL
3. Website type : Dynamic
4. .htaccess usage : High
5. Apache modules enabled : mod_rewrite and mod_spelling

**REWRITE CODE:**

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)-(.+)~(.+)\.html$ gallery-model.php?gallnm=$1&newnm=$2&modelid=$3
```

There are 2 issues that has to be solved,

**1. URLs duplicate issue 
2. Query string append in URL**

**ISSUE #1 : URLs duplicate issue**

According to SEO-MOZ report, there are two different URLs with same content. For example,

Structure of URL : http://www.example.co.uk/galleryname-modelname~modelid.html

URL 1 : http://www.example.co.uk/Shoes-Blackmamba~23.html

URL 2 : http://www.example.co.uk/shoes-blackmamba~23.html

Please note the URL 1 has camel cased text and URL 2 with lower cased text.

A gallery-model.php file makes 100's of records stored in MYSQL db to makes it to display in above mentioned URLs #1 and #2.

NOTE(S) :

1. The variables that are reasonable for parsing the query string all are using 'strtolower'. Double checked and confirmed.
2. If you check the above **REWRITE CODE** you can see [nc] at the last. If I try to manipulate, it returns in a 500 internal server error.

**HOW TO STOP THIS DUPLICATION OF URLs WITH SAME CONTENT BUT DIFFERENT URLs?**

**ISSUE #2 : Query string append in URL**

Please check the **REWRITE CODE** it does a function of rewriting URLs to SEF. Some URLs works fine but rest append the query string. For exmaple,

http://www.example.co.uk/shoes-blackmamba~23.html?gallnm=Shoes&newnm=Blackmamba&modelid=23

NOTE(S) :

1. If you check the above URL you can find the camelcase in query string.
2. The **REWRITE CODE** is being applied so it should not append the variable names and it's current values after the 'URL?' but it does.
3. trim() being used and no mysql case change applied.

**HOW TO ELIMINATE THIS QUERY STRING?**

TRIED SOLUTIONS for issues #1 and #2:

1. mod_spelling.c enabled but it returned in 500 internal server error.
2. Force URL to lower case after several google search doesn't work good.

I look forward for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:
1. Get the current URL.
2. Preg_match for "?"
3. Explode with "?"
4. Redirect to exploded array[0].

Code as below:

```
//Force all lower case - begins

//Step 1 : To get current URL
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

//Step : 2
if (preg_match('/?/',$camel)) {
        $expurl = (explode("?",$camel)); //Step 3 : Explode with "?"
        header("Location: $expurl[0]"); //Step 4 : Redirect to exploded array[0].
    }
```